# Ошибка с пустом значением в Editext

Tags: android, edittext

В общем, интереса ради делаю примитивный конвертер валют. Проблема в том, что я в EditText не могу оставить пустое значение, то есть убрать все цифры, приложение начинается крашиться с ошибкой Empty String. Понимаю, что не правильно передаю значения, но не могу понять как это исправить. Подскажите пожалуйста каким в моем (да, я понимаю, что все тут выглядит бредово, но я учусь) случае будет лучшим решением. Если конечно в этом куске нечта можно что-то сделать. Вот нечто, напоминающее код:

```
package com.loader.currencytest.NewPrototype;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.loader.currencytest.MainActivity;
import com.loader.currencytest.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class UsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener {

EditText mount_number1;
TextView result_pount;
TextView currency_equally_gbp;
TextView result_eur;
TextView currency_equally_eur;
TextView result_jpn;
TextView currency_equally_jpn;

LinearLayout block_wrap;


private RequestQueue mQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.usa_activity);
    mount_number1 = findViewById(R.id.mount_number1);

    result_pount = findViewById(R.id.result_pnd);
    currency_equally_gbp = findViewById(R.id.currency_equally_gbp);

    result_eur = findViewById(R.id.result_eur);
    currency_equally_eur = findViewById(R.id.currency_equall_eur);

    result_jpn = findViewById(R.id.result_jpn);
    currency_equally_jpn = findViewById(R.id.currency_equally_jpn);

    btn_eur = findViewById(R.id.btn_eur);
    btn_pnd = findViewById(R.id.btn_pnd);
    btn_jpn = findViewById(R.id.btn_jpn);
    block_wrap = findViewById(R.id.block_wrap);

    btn_eur.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_jpn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_pnd.setOnClickListener(this);

    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJson();


        mount_number1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "DefaultLocale"})
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            final double a = Double.parseDouble(mount_number1.getText().toString().trim());
            String inputText = currency_equally_eur.getText().toString().trim();

            double eur = Double.parseDouble(currency_equally_eur.getText().toString().trim());
            double gbp = Double.parseDouble(currency_equally_gbp.getText().toString().trim());
            double jpy = Double.parseDouble(currency_equally_jpn.getText().toString().trim());


            result_eur.setText(String.format("%.2f", a*eur));
            result_pount.setText(String.format("%.2f", a*gbp));
            result_jpn.setText(String.format("%.2f", a*jpy));



        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {



        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



        }
    });




}



private void  parseJson() {

    String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR,GBP,JPY";
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("rates");

                        String addJPY = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getString("JPY")));
                        String addGBP = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getString("GBP")));
                        String addEUR = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getString("EUR")));


                        currency_equally_gbp.setText(addGBP);
                        currency_equally_jpn.setText(addJPY);
                        currency_equally_eur.setText(addEUR);

                        mount_number1.setText("1");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(UsActivity.this, "Check your internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}



}
```

Вот xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/block_wrap"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/corners"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:focusable="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/usa"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="USD"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="US Dollar"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/mount_number1"
            android:textColor="#03dbfc"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text=" "
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
     android:id="@+id/btn_pnd"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/corners"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:focusable="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:src="@drawable/brit"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/abb_currency"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="GBP"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="Pound"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/result_pnd"
                android:textColor="#03dbfc"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:text="0"

                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorNext"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_equally_gbp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/btn_eur"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/corners"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:focusable="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:src="@drawable/euro1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="EUR"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="Euro"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/result_pound"
                android:textColor="#03dbfc"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:text="0"

                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorNext"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_equall_eur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
     android:id="@+id/btn_jpn"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/corners"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:focusable="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:src="@drawable/yap"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="YPG"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/currency_name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="Yen"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/wrap_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/result_jpn"
                android:textColor="#03dbfc"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:text="0"

                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorNext"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_equally_jpn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: очевидно что не нужно выполнять никаких действий, если поле пустое. сделайте условие перед запуском метода

Comment: @PalmerEldrich, во первых покажите пожалуйста какая ошибка получается в логах в результате выполнения кода, а во вторых вот линк на то как в андроид принято оформлять код, вдруг что-то новое узнаете) -> https://habr.com/en/company/simbirsoft/blog/344470/